# Rings or algebras with many nilpotent elements and efficient computation

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory

Searching the web for '"quantum computer" nilpotent'
returns many results, so maybe the question is ontopic
for this site.

> Can a quantum computer solve the following mathematical
> problem:

This is related to an open problem, so likely the answer is negative.

The problem is [Cycle Enumeration using Nilpotent Adjacency
Matrices with Algorithm Runtime Comparisons](https://members.loria.fr/RSchott/staceyAISCfinalmarch10.pdf) pp 2-3 about zeon algebra.

Is there commutative ring or commutative algebra $R$ with the following properties:

1. There are $n$ nilpotent elements $a_i$ satisfying $a_i^2=0$
2. $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n \ne 0$.
3. Computation in $R$ is efficient: for an $n$ by $n$ matrix $M$
   with entries zero and $a_i$, for natural $m$ we can compute
   $M^m$ in time polynomial in $nm$.

If we omit the efficiency constraint, the answer is easy:

Take $R=K[a_1,a_2,...a_n]/(a_1^2,a_2^2,...a_n^2)$ for any ring $K$.

Comment: Could you include a reference for where the open problem was considered?

Comment: @AHusain I edited with reference and allowing algebra as solution.

Comment: There it looks like the coefficient ring is the integers because it is counting paths as natural numbers. You could replace that by Z_2 and count only whether or not there are even or odd numbers of k length paths from v_i to v_j with specified zeta_I

Comment: @AHusain Yes, the paper is working over the integers. If you can compute powers of the matrix modulo $2$ (working over Z/2Z) this will be very interesting result I believe.

Comment: Crossposted to MO:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364267/rings-or-algebras-with-many-nilpotent-elements-and-efficient-computation